# Define __MyCompanyName__ in Xcode per project?

Tags: xcode

I've seen how to define the `__MyCompanyName__` macro value that displays in all header comments in XCode by defining it globally via a terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "My Company";}'
```

However, I do work under multiple company names and would like an easy way to switch this depending on what project I'm working on.  I realize that I can just write a simple shell script to do this, but then I still have to remember to run it every time I open a project.  Am I missing an easy way to define this per project statically somewhere?  (This seems like a silly hoop to have to jump through... Apple, hello?)

Comment: Note that you can set the global default by specifying your company name in Address Book. No need for `defaults write ...`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that somewhere.  Still doesn't really address my issue though ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Xcode 3.2 (IIRC) this is a per-project setting.
Just "Get Info" on your project in Xcode. It's right there on the "General" tab.

**Update**
The above answer is for Xcode 3.2. See Sri Sankaran's & aeldron's answers below for Xcode 4.

**Update**
Also appropriate for Xcode 4 is the first part of trtwn's answer below.  in other words, setting the "company" in the address book is one way to solve the problem in case the company will always be the same for all New files created in Xcode on a particular mac.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I had not found that setting.  Of course, when you create a new project, the default template files you get will always have the globally-defined value, but it looks like changing this setting will apply correctly to new files added to the project going forward.  I guess that's about as good as I'm going to get -- thanks!

Comment: Reference aeldron's response for the XCode 4 solution

Answer (score 122):

Screenshot of Xcode 4.1.

[image: @neoneye See screenshot of how it's done with Xcode 4.1 (OS X Lion -- if that matters).]

Comment: +1 Ahem, this is the real answer for xcode 4+ .. thanks for the hand holding graphic!!!

Answer (score 51):

You can set the value in the project's info settings.  In Xcode 4:

1. select the blue project icon
2. open the Utilities Pane if it's closed (Option+Command+1)
3. Type in the Organization field in the Project Document section.

Voila!

[image]

Comment: anyway to set it before you create the template project, so you don't have to go search and replace the occurences created by template before you can change the organization?

Comment: I cannot find any Organization field in the settings. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 17):

As for Xcode 4, the Release Notes state

> The ORGANIZATIONNAME substitution value in templates is now replaced with the Company Name from the current user’s Address Book card if present, rather than _*MyCompanyName*_. If the PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions user default has already been set, it will be honored.

Yet, the latter was not the case for me.

Answer (score 7):

@weichsel's answer is accepted as it solves this for most *normal* people ;), but I switch this setting often enough that getting the template-generated files with the statically-defined company name is  still a bit of an annoyance each time I start a new project.  Having to do the "Get Info then type the name" dance also takes up too much time if you do it often enough.  Here's my ultimate solution:

- Create a folder like "Set Company" with my shell scripts in it for each company I use
- Each script contains a version of this terminal command specific to each company:

  `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "My Company";}'`
- I make each script executable so that I can simply double-click in Finder to set my current company.  [This page](http://adamyoung.net/OS-X-Run-Shell-Scripts-From-Finder) helped me set this up.  Basically, you just

  - Rename each **.sh** script file to **.command**
  - Set the permissions of each script to be executable.  I couldn't figure out how to do this in Finder, but in terminal it's simply `chmod +x mycompany.command`

Easy as that.  Now to start a new project I simply double-click whichever company I plan to use then I'm off to coding.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Fwiw, I [don't believe it's possible to '+x equivalent' using the Finder](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3910639), so you didn't miss anything (two years ago). You can `chmod XXX` where `X` is even -- but no odds (so no execute) from Get Info. You're absolutely right; that's not a real smooth error message there from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Best fix for **My Company.** in XCode 4:

Open your Address Book card and give yourself a company name. You should do this from System Preferences to make sure you are changing the correct User.

On you Mac –> Select System Preferences –> Select Users and Groups –> Click once on Your User ID –> Click on Address Book Card ‘Open’ button. This is the contact associated with your User account. Add a company name here (just under your name). Close XCode if it’s open. Open Xcode and give it a try. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open **Contacts**
2. Make sure you are on the contact list
3. Make sure your contact card is assigned to "**My Card**" if not select it from "**Make this My Card**" from Card menu.
   [image]
4. Make sure that your **company** is set on your card.
5. Your card should look like this: (on your picture is should say "**me**")
   [image]

Next time you create a new project or create a new file your company name will be as it is defined in your contact card.