# How to change the default company name in Xcode 4.0 (build 4A304a)

Tags: xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I set my company name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956464/where-do-i-set-my-company-name)

I installed Xcode 4.0 (build 4A304a) just now. The default company name can't be updated via defaults command on my side. I googled a lot and tried many solutions (AddressBook, com.apple.Xcode and com.apple.dt.Xcode plist file ...) mentioned by others. None works for me...

It's not a big issue and I can even ignore it. But I just want to know why and how.

Did you meet with this issue with Xcode 4? Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 41):

In XCode 4, open up your project. Select the top-most item in the Project Navigator (MyProjectName, 1 target, iOS SDK 4.3 -- or whatever). Open up the file inspector (View->Utilities). In the Project Document section, you should see an "Organization" line. Edit that, and new files that you create will display the new organization name. This is a project setting, hence you'll have to do it for every project. You'll have to search-and-replace to fix up any existing files.

For new projects that you create, the Organization Name will be whatever the value was on the previously open project. (You can edit it when creating the new project.)

If the Organization Name entry in the UI is blank (and for your very first project ever in XCode maybe?) it'll pull the business name from the "Me" card in your address book.

Comment: maybe @Linkou should accept this answer, it absolutely worked for me

Answer (score 7):

This works for me!

> The ORGANIZATIONNAME substitution value in templates is now replaced with the Company Name from the current user’s Address Book card if present, rather than *MyCompanyName*. If the PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions user default has already been set, it will be honored.
>
> That we have to set the company name of my name card in address book of the MacOSX.

from: http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/blog/set-company-name-xcode-4

Answer (score 3):

To clarify as there seems to be a lot of confusion every time I look for this.

XCode will pull the company name from the 'me' entry in your address book ***IF*** the organisation line in the project document section is blank. You can override your address book entry on a per project basis using the answer given by AndrewS.

Answer (score 2):

No, no, and no. You see the TRUELY weird thing in Xcode 4 is that it's actually pulling the company name from the "Me" entry in your address book. This overrides all previous solutions!

I couldn't figure out why it kept on inserting my old company name.

- Checked the ORGANIZATIONNAME in the command line. That was set as my
  new company name. Fail, it was still overridden.
- Checked the Company Name entry in the Address Book. That was set as
  my new company name. Fail, it was still overridden.
- Changed the company name under the "Me" entry in the Address Book.
  Finally, success!