# "Attaching to <product_name>"

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios4, xcode4, ios-simulator

After create a distribution version, uploaded successfully to the AppStore through the Application Loader. And when I try to restart the development for the new version on XCode.

I edited the Scheme to the debug profile but some has been broken on the project, and after hours of reading and trying ... I'm completelly frustraded ...

I follow this instrucctions https://devforums.apple.com/message/396965#396965

And already try to edit the scheme and select manually the .app file as you can check in this explanation

[XCode 4 hangs at "Attaching to (app name)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name)

but still doesn't works and the "Attaching to" message is still showed ...

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: I have created a new target have added all the resources of the main one and have tried again but still the same problem ... :(((

Comment: Finally work it out ... removing the temporal data on organizer and removing the xuserdata on the xcodeproj element ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally work it out ... removing the temporal data on organizer and removing the xuserdata on the xcodeproj element ...