# Attaching to myApp

Tags: frameworks, xcode4, ios4

i have created a framework which is having some classes( files). 
i recently  added some more classes in it and importing it in my apps(i have checked this framework after adding new files on it, with 3 apps) showing  NO error but showing "Attaching To MyApp".  i have googled but nothing found yet which works for me.  I am using Xcode4 and MAC OS X 10.6.7.

Now if i tried with old version of framework code sometimes it works fine sometimes it's not.
Any one  know reason why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

See answers to question:
[Xcode 4.2. gets stuck "Attaching to myapp" when running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021426/xcode-4-2-gets-stuck-attaching-to-myapp-when-running)

Renaming my "Resources" folder to "Assets" plus Cmd+Option+Shift+K fixed it for me.