# Xcode process launch failed: invalid host string: '(null)'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to learn Objective C. However, when I write some code and run it, xcode says `build sucsessful` but the code does not run. Eventually it comes up saying:

> process launch failed: invalid host string: '(null)'

Please help.

I have also already reinstalled it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832234/xcode-error-failed-to-launch-directory-invalid-host-string-localhost this might help you

Comment: could you provide the some source code. A simple `Single View` application from the templates provided should work without any issues

Comment: And what is your target platform? iOS? Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode error Invalid string localhost

open terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

If it asks for password ,enter password;

copy and paste this commands

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

then press

`control-o`

and then press

`enter`

and then press

`control-x`

then type

```
  dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Thats it !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this couple times and what I did to overcome this are such as:

- Reconnect the cable between Macbook and target device
- Uninstall the app and re-install it

Note that it happened on my old iPhone especially. You should try tinkering around something like above first to make sure that you don't overlook what might be simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that your signing in with developer profile not distribution in your build setting provisioning profile.

hope it helps.

Comment: sorry i am new to xcode i signed in with a free developer account with my apple id, is that what you meant.

Comment: even if your sign in with developer account restart your xcode and then try again hope helps.