# XCode 4.3.2 Won't attach to debugger

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, osx-lion

I finally upgraded to Lion (from SL & Xcode 4.2). I am now running:

- Current Lion 10.7.3
- Current Xcode 4.3.2
- Current Simulator(s) 5.1, 5.0, and 4.3 installed.

I've backed way off from my current production apps, and created a simple single view universal hello world app, to try to get some form of simulator debugging working.

With my new simple app, I CAN still debug on device, but NOT on any simulator I have installed. It launches the simulator, eventually installs the app under test, but never attaches to it, and the app never progresses pass the launch image. (One note, I can launch the app from the simulator...  so, it did get built and installed correctly, although took a bit longer than I was used to with SL & 4.2)

Xcode just sits there waiting to connect. The worrisome part is that I can't stop this (stop button, try to close the project, stopping the task) at all, and must force-quit Xcode.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!

-eric

Comment: As a follow up, I have completely started over...  I have a nice clean dev machine now, and all things have returned to their normal (Well, as normal as can be).  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the debug option from LLDB to GDB by editing the scheme. 
see also http://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/xcode-4-3-1-cannot-attach-to-ios-simulator/

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks Adraman! Can't really see if this helped anymore, but I did have a friend also suggest this (after my flush).  Hope this helps someone else who gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I am ready to scream with the same problem, although in my case the simulator works at home when I'm connected to my router, but when at the cottage and tethered to Personal Hotspot, it hangs at "Attaching to...".  It will, however, run on the iPad with no problems.

My network setup is thing only thing that has changed.  I was running the app in the simulator yesterday with no problems, and have not made any code changes since then.

Apple is mute on the topic, despite dozens of questions on their Dev forum, which is infuriating.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm about a few days out from a complete OSX level re-install...