# Ios 6 simulator stuck on splash screen

Tags: ios6, ios-simulator

I am using Mac os 10.8.2, and Xcode 4.5.2, when i try to run my app in ios 5/5.1 simulator its working fine, but when i try to run the App in ios 6 simulator it get stuck with blank screen. can anybody let me know what the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this issue a while ago. Here's what helped me:

> 1. In your iOS simulator, reset content and settings
> 2. quit your iOS simulator
> 3. Quit and reopen your Xcode project
> 4. in Xcode, click Product > Edit Scheme. Change debugger from LLDB to GDB (or none)
> 5. In Xcode, click Product > Hold down the option button on your keyboard and click 'Clean build folder'
> 6. Run your project

This works for me... sometimes when I have this error. Here's a good link for some other options for what could be going wrong:

[XCode 4 hangs at "Attaching to (app name)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name)

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

**I had the same issue:** In my case, the cause apparently was:

> - two singletons,
> - each of whom had a pointer to the other,
> - in its designated initializer.

Like a figure eight, initializing #1 led to initializing the other (#2), which lead to *an attempt* to initialize #1 again -- but as a singleton, this (at least, I conjecture that this) meant blowing away the memory address that had the thread - like going back in time and causing your parents to never meet. So the thread was lost without even an error, just a hang.

iOS 8.x, Xcode 6.x, ObjC

Comment: Can you please provide a little more information about this problem? I think I'm having the same issue and have no clue how to get rid of this.

Comment: For me, I solved the problem by moving the respective pointers out of the respective initializer methods.

Comment: Specifically, my singletons are a DataManager and APIClient respectively. The DataManager occasionally needs data from the API, and the APIClient occasionally wants to store data or interact with the DataManager. [I am open to better ways of doing this, of course]. Now, the DataManager just initializes a reference to the APIClient singleton in the method that needs it, rather than in the DataManger's init (and vice versa).

Comment: Update: In Swift, making one of the Singleton's references to the other `lazy` breaks the circle and solves the problem I had experienced (that, and better SOLID design, it goes without saying).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was not a caching issue. The issue was that the program was caught in an infinite loop which got triggered right at the start of the application.

Try and see if this is your case.