# App struck in splash screen or launch screen in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Sometimes app is working fine, but sometimes it will get stuck in the launch screen.

I tried many things like changing the provisioning profile, restarting my Mac, quiting Xcode, and quitting the iPhone Simulator.

Xcode version is 7.3.0, macOS 10.11.4

I don't know what to do next. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: any error message?

Comment: No error message.After some time it is giving memory warning.

Comment: I am using Swreavel ViewController in first screen.before that in first launch i am showing some settings screen.

Comment: if those are making problem then sometimes it is running.

Comment: you use development certificates only and try.

Comment: its working for lower version.but due to SWReavelViewcontroller its not working in ios9

Answer (score 2):

If your app hangs at launch, you should check your AppDelegate's `didFinishingLaunching` and the initial view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it might be taking some time to appear.

Check the code what you are running in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Any **Server** calls making it to take that much time.

Try the way by `debugging` from `AppDelegate` to `viewDidLoad` method of initial **viewcontroller**.

Comment: No server calls,i waited till it goes.After 5minute it is showing memory warning

Comment: check this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449224/ios-6-simulator-stuck-on-splash-screen) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837237/app-stuck-in-splash-screen-on-ios-9-with-no-error)