# iPhone up no longer loads into device or emulater, just does nothing when i run it

Tags: iphone

When I try to run my app, it builds with no errors, but will not run.
At the top of the Xcode window it says “Attaching to golfflixlight” with a little animation underneath.

I let it run for 20 minutes and gave up, I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recurring scourge of Xcode. It is there to make our lives miserable. The solution is very elusive, and I have yet to read a single, coherent explanation what's happening.

Take a look [at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name), it might give you some idea how to solve your conundrum. Personally, nothing works for me other than going to Edit Scheme, and setting the debugger to GDB. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The debugger was allready set to GDB

Comment: No problem, hope you got it working. Otherwise, visit the SO question in my answer, it pertains to the problem you have and has a number of possible remedies you could try.