# Xcode not able to attach application to Iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My OS version of Mac OS X 10.7.5 Lion, Xcode Version is 4.5.
I am creating any new application or running any old application on my macbook xcode will not able to deploy the application on any version of simulator.

& it works fine if I am attached to a high speed connection xcode will work properly but offline  it says "Attaching to appName" infinitely & hangs...

I googled but no help.

any suggestion, links much appreciated.... Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question regarding how the network connection affects the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4 hangs at "Attaching to (app name)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382968/xcode-4-hangs-at-attaching-to-app-name)

Comment: if i connected with net connection Xcode will work normally no issue.but if I am working offline not able to attach to application file to simulator