# Setup screen iOS - Name edits

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am looking to change those two info in XCode showing in the simulator when the App is installed.

Do you know where I should look for (see attached screenshot), the name and the copyright.

[image]

I already tried to change the bundle name and target without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a file called LaunchScreen.xib in your project. It is automatically created as part of the project template, and it shows the name of the project (at the time of creation - that's why you had no luck changing the settings) and the [organization name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956464/where-do-i-set-my-company-name).

[image: launchscreen]

You can customize this screen as you wish (e.g. show a logo), or get rid of it altogether - then you need to provide the good old 'Default*.png' files, and indicate in the Project settings that you don't want to use a Launch Screen File.

Comment: Thanks, just a quick info there is something called "Splash Screen" with iOS, do you know if this is the same thing as this?

Comment: The Splash Screen could also refer to the Default.png - the official name is Launch Screen File.