# Can I set custom developer's name for creating files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, project-settings

When Xcode creates new textual file, it contains such header:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  application name
//
//  Created by Developer Name on 25.07.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 company. All rights reserved.
//
```

`Application name` and `company` values gives from project when developer's name from macOS account

Can I set custom developer's name for project in Xcode directly, without changing or setting up OS account?

It needed for example when one mac uses for work and home projects. I want to set my real name for work projects and pen name for home.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I set my company name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956464/where-do-i-set-my-company-name)

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSzymczyk! That question is not about developer's name but I found answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752890/mark-szymczyk)'s comment I found answer

For set custom project developer's name `info.plist` file must be edited

Just add row `Copyright (human-readable)` (source code key is `NSHumanReadableCopyright`) and enter needed name:

[image]

Or directly in source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key> <!-- developer name key -->
    <string>Developer Name</string> <!-- developer name value -->
<!-- ... and further ... -->
```